# Wildfly 26.0.1 fails basic authentication when Authorization header has BASIC with all capitals

Tags: java, http, authentication, authorization, wildfly

We are in the process of upgrade of our platform to Wildfly 26.0.1
We noticed that when HTTP request comes in to one of basic auth-protected endpoints , and if the HTTP "Authorization" header has value that starts with the word BASIC - with all capitals - then the request immediately result it HTTP 401 response, despite correct login and password in base64-encoded second part. It works properly if the value starts with "Basic" ("B" in uppercase, the rest is lowercase).

The problem is very similar, if not identical to [this bug](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/WFLY-5618?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=13160586) opened and fixed a few years ago (opened for WF9.0.2, fixed in 10.1.0)

We also confirmed that this issue exist in previous versions of Wildfly, the earliest we were able to reproduce it is WF18, and we also know for sure the 10.1.0 did not have it - as this is the version we trying to migrate from.

Has anyone come across this issue and knows how to tweak configuration / otherwise fix it? Asking clients to use "Basic" instead of "BASIC" is not an option.

```
$ curl -vH "Authorization: BASIC ZnJhbms6cGFzc3dvcmQxMjM=" http://localhost:8080/http-basic/secure
* Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /http-basic/secure HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: BASIC ZnJhbms6cGFzc3dvcmQxMjM=
>
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Expires: 0
< Connection: keep-alive
< WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="RealmUsersRoles"
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 71
< Date: Thu, 10 Mar 2022 15:38:55 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
<html><head><title>Error</title></head><body>Unauthorized</body></html>mark_mac:enstream-identity-warTrunk mwei$

$ curl -vH "Authorization: Basic ZnJhbms6cGFzc3dvcmQxMjM=" http://localhost:8080/http-basic/secure
* Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /http-basic/secure HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Basic ZnJhbms6cGFzc3dvcmQxMjM=
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Expires: 0
< Connection: keep-alive
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Length: 206
< Date: Thu, 10 Mar 2022 15:39:11 GMT
<
<html><head><title>servlet-security</title></head><body>
<h1>Successfully called Secured Servlet </h1>
<p>Principal : frank</p>
<p>Remote User : frank</p>
<p>Authentication Type : BASIC</p>
</body></html>
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Comment: If you can't move your client to use standards, can you give some information about your app?  I've written filters for servlet apps and a ContainerRequestFilter for JAX-RS apps that would solve your issue.

Comment: @stdunbar Thank you. As a matter of fact, the RFC 7235 says that HTTP Authentication Basic header should not be case sensitive, so using BASIC shouldn't cause issues. One of earlier Undertow bugs refers to this RFC and confirms that, see the link below. Looks like this bug was active in some earlier releases, than was fixed, and probably was reintroduced at some point later on. https://issues.redhat.com/browse/UNDERTOW-629

Comment: @stdunbar As of our app,  we expose bunch of restful APIs, we use resteasy, which is JAX-RS implementation

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mike - I missed that the  *value* is case insensitive too (HTTP keys have always been case insensitive).  Below is what I have used for my own JaxRS services.

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javax.annotation.Priority;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException;
import javax.ws.rs.NotAuthorizedException;
import javax.ws.rs.Priorities;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.container.PreMatching;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.SecurityContext;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.Principal;
import java.util.Base64;


@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
@PreMatching
public class AuthContainerRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthContainerRequestFilter.class);

    private static final Boolean authEnabled = Boolean.TRUE;

    @Context
    private HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse;


    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext)  {

        SamplePrincipal samplePrincipal;

        if( authEnabled ) {   
            String authToken = containerRequestContext.getHeaderString("Authorization");

            if (authToken == null) {
                logger.warn("this request has no Authorization header or parameter");
                httpServletResponse.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=\"Sample Service\", charset=\"UTF-8\"");
                throw new NotAuthorizedException(Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED)
                        .entity("no authorization header")
                        .type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
                        .build());
            }

            if (!authToken.toLowerCase().startsWith("basic")) {

                httpServletResponse.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=\"Sample Service\", charset=\"UTF-8\"");
                throw new NotAuthorizedException(Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED)
                        .entity("expected Basic auth for Authorization header")
                        .type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
                        .build());
            }

            String[] basicAuthHeaderParts = authToken.split(" ");
            if (basicAuthHeaderParts.length != 2) {
                httpServletResponse.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=\"Sample Service\", charset=\"UTF-8\"");
                throw new BadRequestException(Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)
                        .entity("malformed Basic auth for Authorization header - missing auth value")
                        .type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
                        .build());
            }

            String userAndPassword = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(basicAuthHeaderParts[1]), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            String[] userAndPasswordValues = userAndPassword.split(":");

            if (userAndPasswordValues.length != 2) {
                httpServletResponse.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=\"Sample Service\", charset=\"UTF-8\"");
                throw new BadRequestException(Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)
                        .entity("malformed Basic auth for Authorization header - can't split user/password")
                        .type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
                        .build());
            }
          
            // validate user/password combo

            // fill the principal with the appropriate values.
            // this allows for the @RolesAllowed annotation too.

            samplePrincipal = new SamplePrincipal(userAndPasswordValues[0], "Some Name");
            samplePrincipal.addRole("normal");
        }
        else {
            samplePrincipal = new SamplePrincipal("blah@blah.com", "Some Name");
        }

        containerRequestContext.setSecurityContext(new SecurityContext() {
            @Override
            public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
                return samplePrincipal;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean isUserInRole(String role) {
                return samplePrincipal.isUserInRole(role);
            }
            @Override
            public boolean isSecure() {
                return containerRequestContext.getUriInfo().getAbsolutePath().toString().startsWith("https");
            }
            @Override
            public String getAuthenticationScheme() {
                return SecurityContext.BASIC_AUTH;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

with the SamplePrincipal:

```
import java.security.Principal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class SamplePrincipal implements Principal {

    private String userName;
    private String name;
    private List<String> roles = null;


    public SamplePrincipal(String userName, String name) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void addRole(String role) {
        if( roles == null)
            roles = new ArrayList<>();

        roles.add(role);
    }

    public void setRoles(List<String> roles) {
        this.roles = new ArrayList<>(roles);
    }

    public boolean isUserInRole(String role) {
        if( roles == null )
            return false;

        return roles.contains(role);
    }
}
```

As part of my code I use the `@RolesAllowed` annotation on my services to validate the permission.  Ultimately I did a DB query for the user/password/roll information.

I do realize that I'm re-writing code that already exists but it simplified an application that had an existing user database that was more complicated than the default Wildfly configuration allowed me to handle.  In your case there is really just a single line from this that needs to exist where the header is compared with the string "basic".  I'm not positive that this is worth it but when the bug comes back into Undertow you'll be ready I guess.